# Youtube API limits increase

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'd like to increase default quota limits from 10000 to more than 1M. Is it posible and how much time approximately it will take? To increase limits I'll send request to https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en form.

Comment: Good luck. We are dealing with the same issue on our end. We heard nothing back from them yet...

Answer (score 1):

I've submitted the same form and haven't heard a decision in over five weeks. The last message was:

"Thanks for your response to the audit form. We will  conduct our audit based on the information you provided.  We will notify you if additional information is needed or when we’ve completed our review.

Thank you for your cooperation.

Regards,

YouTube API Compliance Team"

Comment: Finally did hear back after around 5 or 6 weeks since the audit ended. They approved my increase!

Answer (score 0):

There's a hack to get more quota limit, though I am not sure if it can be used for 1 million units, I have personally used it to get 50k units or so.

Just create multiple API keys in the Google developer console. And loop through the list of these API keys.

Again this is not a permanent solution, but you can use it till your request gets approved.